# Iron-router set notFoundTemplate when no data found in database

Tags: meteor, iron-router

How can I set a layout when my data function returns null.

For example, in the route below, when chefs is null, I would like to render my 'notFound' template.

```
Router.route('/vendors/chefs/:_url', {
  template: 'chefs',
  data: function() {
    var chefs = Chef_db.findOne({url: this.params._url});
    return chefs;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the notFoundTemplate in the documentation: https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md

You can apply it globally:

> `Router.plugin('dataNotFound', {notFoundTemplate: 'notFound'});`

Or you can apply it to specific routes using the except/only options:

> ```
> Router.plugin('dataNotFound', {
>   notFoundTemplate: 'NotFound', 
>   except: ['server.route']
>   // or only: ['routeOne', 'routeTwo']
> });
> ```

Answer (score 0):

There's a built-in plugin for that. It's called `dataNotFound`. It's mentioned in the [iron:router guide](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#plugins).